# How to handle Render Blocking Resource

Tags: html, css

I have checked my website url in Google Page Insite console (https://developers.google.com/speed/pagespeed/insights/) and it shows me render blocking resources event I have added the media attribute in all linked css.
I have already added his suggestion to add media attribute in link tag.

```
<link href="css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen">
```

-->

```
<link id="bodybg" href="bodybg/bg8.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="all">
```

Please tell me the solution to improve my website score on google page insight.

Comment: we kind of need to know the url. Usually render blocking resources means you have things in the head tag. So either move them in the body or find a way to bundle everything as one (like Webpack) does and serve them. Kind of hard to say without knowing what's the actual problem.